# iOS compatible live mp4 stream

Tags: ios, ffmpeg, mp4, h.264

I have a video source which gives me a raw h264 stream. I need to re-stream this live input in a way it is cross-compatible and playable without any plugin. I've tried using ffmpeg+ffserver to produce a fragmented mp4, but unfortunately my iPhone isn't playing it.

Is there a way to make it (raw h264 in mp4 container) playable in iOS's Safari, or maybe another cross-platform container?

Ps: i'm using a raspberry pi 3 to host ffmpeg processes, so i'm avoiding re encoding tasks; instead i'm just trying to fit my raw h264 in a "ios-compatible" container and make it accessible through a media server.

Comment: Since this is coming up when searching for the title, you can play these raw MP4 streams using an [ffmpeg port](https://github.com/hysoo/ffmpeg-avplayer-for-ios-tvos). It's paid unfortunately but there is a demo library. If you're a bit handy with REing it's not hard to patch but I wouldn't do that in any official capacity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For live streams you must use `HTTP Live Streaming` (`HLS`) with either the traditional `MPEG-TS` or `fMP4` for newer iOS versions (see Apple HLS [examples](https://developer.apple.com/streaming/examples/)).

With `FFmpeg` you can use the [hls](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#hls-1) muxer. The `hls_segment_type` option is used to choose between `mpegts` and `fmp4`.